# How do I sort an ArrayList containing more than 1 parameter per object alphabetically?

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist

Greetings (Don't know if the title makes sense)

I have an `ArrayList` which can contain a different amount of objects in it.

Example

```
private ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
var list = web.Lists[ListName];

items.Add(new { GroupName = value });

foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
   items.Add(new { GroupName = value, ItemID = item.ID, ItemName = item.Name });
}
```

As you can see above, I have an object only containing `GroupName` and then an object containing `GroupName`, `ItemID` and `ItemName`

What I want to do is to sort all the items by their `ItemName`.

I have no issue sorting it when it's only one parameter, but when it's multiple parameters, I'm clueless. How do I do this?

Comment: @Ziga, it would help if you gave an example of what you wish to sort by and the resulting order.

Comment: Is there any way you can use a typed `List<SPListItem>` instead of an untyped `ArrayList`?

Comment: And is it possible for you to use LINQ?

Comment: Should items not containing an `ItemName` go first or last?

Comment: @Juliet No, because as you can see in my post, the object can variet from only having 1 paratemer to contain 3 parameters. Therefor I cannot specify it as simple as that.

Comment: @Yet Yes it is possible for me to use LINQ. I just don't know how to implement LINQ in to this.

I tried doing the following `items.Cast<SPListItem>().OrderBy((x,y) => x.Title.CompareTo(y));` but Y is undefined, thus I cannot compare it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Sort before adding to the new arraylist

```
foreach(SPListItem item in list.Items.Cast<SPListItem>.OrderBy(i => i.Name))
{
   items.Add(new { GroupName = value, ItemID = item.ID, ItemName = item.Name });
}
```

Newer EDIT:
If you just want an enumerable collection (without the arraylist, in which you cannot extract the items from easily), you could just use the LINQ Select operator.

```
var items = ist.Items.Cast<SPListItem>.OrderBy(i => i.Name).Select(i => new { GroupName = value, ItemID = i.ID, ItemName = i.Name });
```

Comment: @Yet I get this error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem'.

Comment: Oh, you are using an anonymousType, I though you used the SPListItem type. Well one thing you could do is to name the anonymous type, and then cast it to the right format. If you name it Item then you should cast to Item instead of SPListItem

Comment: @Yet can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I have reupdated my answer, by sorting before you create the anonymous types. (But you can run into trouble when trying to get the data out of the anonymous type from the arraylist, as you can not cast to an anonymous type)

Comment: @Yet Thanks for your help. I decided to go with a custom class containing definitions of the 4 parameters and sorted before creating the new items.